# OpenVPN and NGINX on same server showing clients real IP and not VPN public IP

Tags: nginx, openvpn

We have a server with NGINX and OpenVPN set up on the same system.

OpenVPN client successfully connects and gets the OpenVPN servers public IP address when visiting external internet resources as normal, but if we browse to the servers NGINX websites my actual OpenVPN clients IPv4 addresses are seen and not the VPN servers public IP.

The reason I want OpenVPN clients to have the server public IP address when browsing the NGINX websites is so that they do not need to enter http auth passwords using the rule below.

```
 location / {
        satisfy any;
        allow [Server_Public_IP]/32;
        auth_basic "Development Area";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What is the domain name of the website? What is the IP address the clients sees when it resolves the domain name?

Comment: Multiple global TLDs and they all resolve to the NGINX/OpenVPN server public IP address

Comment: How does the routing table of OpenVPN clients look?

Comment: Here it is: https://imgur.com/a/NvGryst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that OpenVPN clients have their default gateway set to `10.8.0.1`, which is the VPN server's IP address.

This means that clients send all their outgoing traffic via the VPN tunnel, and the source address is then the VPN tunnel client end IP address.

To solve this, you would need to somehow exclude the server's public IP address from being router via the VPN tunnel.

If the VPN is only needed to communicate with some IP networks, then you can explicitly configure those in the OpenVPN server `push route` statements.

Another less feasible solution is to explicitly route all IP addresses via the VPN except for the public IP address. This creates quite a big routing table in client.

If the requirement is to route all IP addresses via the VPN server, then the only practical solution is to add:

```
allow 10.8.0.0/24;
```

to nginx configuration, so that VPN tunnel users are allowed to access the service.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. I ended up adding a second public IP and changing the OpenVPN server to listen on that instead.